# assign output of help to a variable instead of stdout in python

Tags: python

I want to do something like this in the python interpreter.

```
myhelp = help(myclass)
```

but the output goes to stdout.  Is it possible to assign it to a variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `pydoc`... `import pydoc; myhelp = pydoc.render_doc(myclass)`

Comment: @AChampion I can't seem to find a question related to this, maybe it would be good to post your comment as an answer since it is a pretty good concise way to actually store the help data. For anyone else looking to do this, would be helpful as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture stdout while `help(myclass)` runs:

```
from cStringIO import StringIO
import sys

stdout = sys.stdout
buffer = StringIO()
sys.stdout = buffer

help(myclass)

sys.stdout = stdout

myhelp = buffer.getvalue()
```

Comment: Just wanted to add the Python 3 friendly support for this. That to use `StringIO`, you have to import from `io` -> `from io import StringIO`